# Hosting on Raspberry Pi 3 vs DigitalOcean

Tags: pi-3

I was thinking about hosting a website and a blog (both written in Node.js). Between a Raspberry Pi 3 (on my home internet connection) and the $10/month droplet (1GB RAM and 1 core) on DigitalOcean, which would be the more economic option? Thanks!

EDIT: Both the Pi 3 and the DO droplet can be put behind Cloudflare.

Comment: It's worth noting, that even the $5 (512 MB of RAM) DO droplet will absolutely destroy an RPi 3 in terms of performance.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Could you explain to me how so?

Comment: DO has solid state drives, the RPi has an SD card. DO has enterprise grade Xeon processors, the RPi has a small ARM processor.

Comment: I'm not trying to say that the RPi is a bad product, but the two really aren't comparable.

Comment: DO also has fatter network pipes and keeps working when I'm away from home and there's a power outage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't count the cost of your home internet connection and have the Pi3  there is no competition on cost, Hosting on your Pi will cost you approximately $1 a month (the cost of the electricity) to run and the other $10.

But the more important criteria are

- Security (do you really have the skills to properly harden and protect your Pi and every computer on your LAN, as you will be letting an attacker past your first line of defense)
- The time required to properly administer the two systems (backups, log monitoring, updating software etc.).
- Performance can your internet connection and Pi reasonably meet the load you expect.

When these things are considered digitalOcean wins hands down.

Comment: Security isn't much different on a DO droplet. It's a mostly unmanaged (by DO) VM in which you need to take car of security yourself.

Comment: @Jacobm001 yeah but they have backup capabilities that the OP would have to setup, they also have some network monitoring that can alert (and notify the OP if only after they have shut down his site). As well as some email features to prevent their machines being blacklisted. They also start from the deny everything rule which the Pi doesn't. For example no firewall by default on the Pi.

Comment: There's also the consideration that a compromise on a hosted machine might result in the loss of whatever's on that hosted machine. The compromise of a machine hosted on your home network might well result in the compromise and possible loss of other systems on your internal network. You need to be a lot more judicious before letting strangers into your home.